# Using jQuery mobile to update DOM after form POST

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile's form submission is handled automatically with AJAX.  However it isn't clear how to handle the Response.  I want to update the page with some JSON coming back from the server.  Do I need to disable jQuery Mobile's form AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend reading about `progressive enhancement` which is a main idea with which jQuery Mobile's architecture was created. The answer from the server should be a new HTML document with correct content so that it works with no-JS browsers as well. jQuery Mobile is there to make it come in via AJAX.

If you want to break this rule you have to post the data yourself like you always did with jQuery's `.post()`

Comment: I'm confused by that type of architectural decision for a library that targets mobile browsers.  It's basically saying that instead of sending back {name: "Arch Stanton"} that you should send back an entirely new page in order to display a minor update.

Comment: It's basically saying that instead of supporting only major smartphones your app can work on everything that is capable of displaying HTML. Everything else is an enhancement. Read about it, I didn't like it at first too and I don't always stick to it. Nontheless, they do. But loading json yourself is about 4 lines long, so why not... Just search the stackoverflow for my answers to problems with JQM and AJAX. `.page()` is the key.